# Async tooltip using JSON and kendo.template

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, kendo-ui

I am struggeling with the KendoUI tooltip helper. Currently I am doing the following to get some tooltip information on a grid row:

```
$("#grid").kendoTooltip({
                filter: 'td:nth-child(10)',
                content: function (e) {
                    var template = kendo.template($("#myToolTipTemplate").html());
                    var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
                    var tooltipHtml;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: DetailsURL + "/" + dataItem.Id,
                        async: false
                    }).done(function (data) {   // data.Result is a JSON object from the server with details for the row
                        if (data.Success) {
                            data.Result = data.Result.replace(/null/g, "\"N/A\"");
                            tooltipHtml = template($.parseJSON(data.Result));
                        } else {
                            tooltipHtml = "Ooops!<br>Something went wrong (" + data.Result + ")";
                        }
                    });
                    return tooltipHtml;
                }
            });
```

I would like to get rid of the synchronous ajax call and make it asynchronous. I saw some asynchronous examples where the server delivers the full html, but nothing that works with JSON data from the server, that is then "compiled" via a kendo.template() to html on the client. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Did you tried [`content.url`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#configuration-content.url) parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik helped me here. And, as often, it's easier than guessed..

```
    $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
                filter: 'td:nth-child(10)',
                content: function (e) {
                    var template = kendo.template($("#myToolTipTemplate").html());
                    var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
                    var tooltipHtml;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: DetailsURL + "/" + dataItem.Id,
                        async: false
                    }).done(function (data) {   // data.Result is a JSON object from the server with details for the row
                        if (data.Success) {
                            data.Result = data.Result.replace(/null/g, "\"N/A\"");
                            tooltipHtml = template($.parseJSON(data.Result));
                        } else {
                            tooltipHtml = "Ooops!<br>Something went wrong (" + data.Result + ")";
                        }
                        // set tooltip content here (done callback of the ajax req)
                        e.sender.content.html(tooltipHtml);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the content of the tooltip to be a placeholder value (e.g.
   "Loading..")
2. [Listen for the "Show" event of the tooltip.](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/events)
3. When the show event is triggered, start the request for JSON from the server
4. In the 'done' callback, execute the template, and replace the content of the tooltip with the new html in the 'done' callback

> $("#ID").data("kendoTooltip").popup.wrapper.find(".k-tooltip-content").html("........");